# LUA/Corona sdk: storyboard.gotoScene() not working

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm new to Corona and Lua, so pleas be patient.
So i have a main screen, that I go to from my main file, and it works fine. Then i want to go back to that sceen from a diffrent sceen, and nothing happens (but the "win" is spaming my consol window).

The win function:

```
function win()  
    print("win!");
    storyboard.gotoScene( "MSCREEN.mscreen" );
end
```

Function where i'm calling it:

```
function scene:enterFrame(inEvent)
  --some other stuff
  if (ball.x>display.contentWidth and failFlag==false) then
    win();
  end

 end
```

and my main sceen:

```
local scene = storyboard.newScene();
local bg;
local text;

function scene:createScene(inEvent)
    bg = display.newImage( "MSCREEN/bg.png");
    bg.x = display.contentWidth / 2;
    bg.y = display.contentHeight / 2;

    text=display.newText( "Touch!", 0,0, fontName, 70);
    text.x =display.contentWidth / 2 ;
    text.y =display.contentHeight / 2 +230;  

    self.view:insert(bg);
    self.view:insert(text);
end

function scene:enterFrame(inEvent)
 tekstBujany(text);
end

function scene:touch(inEvent)   
    if inEvent.phase == "ended" then  
        storyboard.gotoScene( "JUMP.GJump" );       
    end
end

function scene:destroyScene(inEvent)
bg:removeSelf();
bg=nil;

text:removeSelf();
text=nil;
end -- End destroyScene().

scene:addEventListener("createScene", scene);
scene:addEventListener("destroyScene", scene);
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", scene);
Runtime:addEventListener("touch",scene);

return scene;
```

**SOLVED**
so adding

```
storyboard.purgeOnSceneChange = true;
```

did the trick, not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "enterFrame" event gets generated at every frame for the Runtime object, so about 30 to 60 times / sec. So win() will be called at every frame if possible. Since win() causes a transition to a new scene, if storyboard.purgeOnSceneChange = false then enterFrame gets called for each scene, leading to constant stream of win() calls and constant stream of transitions to the same scene "MSCREEN.mscreen" (this can't be good). OTOH if you set  storyboard.purgeOnSceneChange = true then the previous scene, here the one with enterFrame that calls win(), is purged so win() will only get called once.

In conclusion, setting  storyboard.purgeOnSceneChange = true may work but I think there is a problem with the logic you have there: a scene transition should not be called at every frame! If you are monitoring for some condition to declare a win, you should either remove the enterFrame callback in win() or ensure the condition is false after win() called once:

```
function scene:enterFrame(inEvent)
  if (ball.x > display.contentWidth and failFlag == false) then
    win();
    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", scene);
  end
end
```

With the guard variable it looks like this:

```
local winCalled = false

function win()
    winCalled = true
    ...
end

function scene:enterFrame(inEvent)
  if (ball.x > display.contentWidth and failFlag == false) then
    win();
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, i was sure that after the first call to goToScene the enter frame is stoped. And as i can go auroud it, i think that keeping storyboard.purgeOnSceneChange = true is a good idea ( i have a lot of sceens) is that right?

Comment: @yeris your solution works but due to a lucky side effect  of the setting you used, so I just wanted to give you another option on case you were looking for a more robust solution. I hope you find it useful to add to your bag of tricks.

Comment: yes, i changed it, the whole logic i mean. I just want to know if keeping storyboard.purgeOnSceneChange = true is a good idea.

Comment: @yeris it is if you want to free resources used by the current scene every time there is a transition to another scene, without exception. So I'd say it should only be used in cases where memory is in short supply or there are other performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with the win() function, it looks like it gets called a lot of times. Set another variable and change it in the method.

```
function win()
    isNotWin = false -- so this method doesn't get called a lot of times.
    print("win!")
    storyboard.gotoScene( "MSCREEN.mscreen" )
end

function scene:enterFrame(inEvent)
    --some other stuff
    if (ball.x>display.contentWidth and failFlag==false and isNotWin == true) then
        win();
    end

end
```

Comment: Thank you, i'm slowly geting a grasp on corona. But slowly ;]

Comment: @yeris not sure what you mean by "low rep"; also, I was refering to Fayer's answer not mine (although if you find mine useful too then by all means :)